# SublimeLinter fails with 'undefined' is not a function, emitter.on(name, listener);

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I've had SublimeLinter working fine with javascript files on my MacBook 10.6 for a while, but now I only see a single error when I save js files. E.g for a file that has a comment on the first line:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'function (name) {     emitter.on(name, listener);     }.bind(this)')
1://
```

I see the same error regardless of what I have in the js file or what project the file is in.

I've tried Removing and Re-installing SublimeLinter, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

See here for a possible fix https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/pull/507#issuecomment-21831056

For me this worked:

> add global.window = {}; on top linter.js

linter.js is located at `.../Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jshint/linter.js`

Comment: Hmmm - that kinda worked and kinda didn't. When I edited linter.js in Sublime Text 2 with the change you suggest, it did fix the error I was having (when I saved linter.js). But as soon as I saved any other js file, Sublime Text quit and then I couldn't restart (quit automatically every time). I removed that line from linter.js with TextMate and then Sublime Text 2 started again. So it's doing something pretty serious!